# Certificate - Give Grant to specific application

Tags: sql-server, sql-grant

Is there any way to give grant to specific application name or IpAddress to access?

I want to give grant of "MyXYZ" application only and restrict other software or application to access that certificate.

I found `GRANT` which restricts for a user like below.

```
GRANT CONTROL ON CERTIFICATE::Certificate1 TO --User Name
```

This is for the user. Now I want to give it for the specific application name.

Comment: Unfortunately SQL Server Permission Hierarchy doesn't understand applications and IPs. You can give `GRANT` to a [Principal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181127.aspx) like a user or a role. This may [help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190998.aspx)

Comment: I think the best you could do is create a [logon trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) and do your own manual checking in there.

Comment: @DavidG this trigger i already know but want to add it in certificate/Symmetric key. Let me know if you heard about it.

Comment: So why isn't the solution to GRANT to a new UserName that only gets used by your application?

Comment: @TabAlleman I want to restrict that user from the sql managment studio or other application use it directly.